# Auto insert blank rows based on value in a cell. data will kept being added to

Tags: google-sheets, insert

Nearly found by searching previous requests but nothing quite fits so:

I would like blank rows inserted after each number corresponding to that figure (plus an extra line)

[image: Original data]

TO

[image: How to look after]

New numbers will be added in column a so would need to re-run the script but only for any new entries each time.

Possible?

Tried other code found searching here but nothing quite fits and I am new to google sheets scripts.

Comment: Post your attempts

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is unclear whether you want to insert rows across the whole sheet or just in column `A`. Please describe your use case in more detail — _why_ are you inserting rows in the first place?

Comment: It would be to insert whole sheet. There would be data in other columns.

Context is, there will be football results and I want to enter goalscorers under the result with a blank row in between each fixture.

Answer (score 0):

> New numbers will be added in column a so would need to re-run the script but only for any new entries each time.

That will be tricky if your intent is to modify the column in place. You would need some way to mark numbers whose blanks have already been inserted. It would be much easier to copy the numbers with blank rows into *another* column, and recreate the column whenever needed.

If you choose the latter approach, you may not need a script, but can use a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula, like this:

```
=let( 
  data, A1:A, 
  lastRow, arrayformula(xmatch("?*", to_text(data), 2, -1)), 
  numbers, filter(data, row(data) <= lastRow), 
  blank, iferror(ø), 
  null, tocol(blank, 1), 
  blanks_, lambda(n, makearray(n, 1, lambda(_, __, blank))), 
  reduce(
    null, numbers, 
    lambda( 
      result, number, 
      { 
        result; 
        number; 
        blanks_(number + 1) 
      } 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

See [let()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13190535), [reduce()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12568597) and [makearray()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569202).